# Fechar popup ao clicar o botão de voltar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Há alguma forma de detectar o click de "voltar"?
Mais necessariamente dos dispositivos móveis (Android é suficiente).

Eu gostaria que, no meu web app, o botão voltar possa chamar determinadas funções, nesse caso, fechar popups.
Vocês tem alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar usar a função:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBack, false)
function onBack(){ /* faz algo ao clicar no botão voltar */ }
```

Comment: não funcionou :( vc já chegou a testá-la?

Comment: pior, que sim eu uso ela nos meus app, da algum erro?

Comment: se vc conseguir postar a parte do código, tbm ajudaria um pouco

Comment: achei uma maneira!! porém não estou conseguindo duplicá-la para usar mais de um popup. vou por o link dela no jsfiddle, se vc quiser tentar ia ser ótimo!

Comment: e sobre tua pergunta, não dá erro, simplesmente sai do web app sem chamar a função

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Limitlessisa/axt1Lqoz/

Comment: tudo que preciso é que, tipo, o botão "share" possa ser duplicado e cada um abrir um popup diferente e fechar os seus respectivos. quando tentei isso um deles sempre acaba perdendo o efeito e eu não entendo o porquê

Comment: Olá fiz um meio rápido aqui, https://jsfiddle.net/3e5dgo0j/1/ veja se é isso, só falta quando clicar em um sair, e vc pode deixar o efeito mais lento tbm, não entendi direito se era isso q vc queria.